# Prometheus - Scrape metrics endpoint over mTLS

Tags: ssl, prometheus

Small question regarding how to scrape a /metrics endpoint over HTTPS, mutual TLS, mutual SSL.

Our Prometheus instance is deployed in a location A.

We then have bunch of micro services deployed all over the places, but never same places as Prometheus.

All micro services successfully expose a /metrics endpoint, ready for Prometheus to come and poll the data. We see the data in Prometheus format already.

All micro services MUST expose the /metrics endpoint over HTTPS, mTLS, mutual TLS, two way SSL.

The test in QA with all micro services exposing the /metrics endpoint over plain old simple HTTP only works perfectly fine. Prometheus is successfully polling all data with this configuration.

```
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'some-job-name'
        metrics_path: /metrics
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - some-host.com:8080
```

However, in Prod, the /metrics MUST be over HTTPS mTLS

The goal of this question is not to create an argument if /metrics endpoints should be over HTTP or HTTPS. The question is really a technical question of how to make Prometheus able to query this /metrics endpoint over HTTPS, mTLS.

What would be the configuration to allow Prometheus scraping those existing data over HTTPS, mTLS please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add tls config in your prometheus config.
You need a certificate which have SAN specified for all your microservices.
So, SAN would be the sub domain of the target url.or dorectly the ip or host name if that is fixed.

Now load the certificate in the all the microservices and prometheus as well. This will allow you to scrape over HTTPS using mTLS.

tls_config:
ca_file: your certificate path.

You need to add a volumemount and volume for the certificate. This will be configured in your helm charts.

Trying running Prometheus version 2.24.0+  and start the Prometheus  on HTTPS itself